# Issue when importing excel file with thousands of lines- ValueError: Passed header=1 but only 1 lines in file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to import an excel file with headers on the second row

```
selected columns=['Student name','Age','Faculty']
data = pd.read_excel(path_in + 'Results\\' + 'Survey_data.xlsx', header = 1,usecols = selected_columns).rename(columns={'Student Name':'First name'}).drop_duplicates()
```

Currently, the excel looks something like this:
Student name    Surname Faculty Major   Scholarship Age L1  TFM Date    Failed subjects
Ana Ruiz    Economics   Finance N   20  N       0
Linda   Peterson    Mathematics Mathematics Y   22  N   2021-12-04  0
Gregory Olsen   Engineering Industrial Engineering  N   21  N       0
Ana Watson  Business    Marketing   N   22  N       0

I have tried including the last column in the selected_columns list but it returns the same error. Would greatly appreciate if someone can let me know why python is not reading all the lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're using Pandas to read excel. you can also consider other libraries, such as **openpyxl**, which could have more options.

Comment: Thanks Lei! In the end, it ended up working if I give the index reference in the usecols argument -usecols=[0,2,5]. Although not sure, why it doesn't work with a list of values.